# Apache rewrite rule leading slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

### Leading slash first argument: ignored?

What's the syntax difference between

```
RewriteRule help help.php?q=noslash [L]     #1
RewriteRule /help help.php?q=withslash [L]  #2
```

If I hit http://localhost/help, it goes to #1, if I hit http://localhost//help it still goes to #1.

Am I right in saying the leading slash in the first argument to RewriteRule is essentially ignored?

### Leading slash second argument: error?

Also, why doesn't this rewrite rule work?

```
RewriteRule help /help.php [L]     #1
```

Putting a leading slash in front of the second arg actually creates a 500 error for the server.  Why?

I should note I'm using a .htaccess file to write these rules in

Comment: What happens if you change the order of both rewriterules? If the first matches (and it does), the second doesn't get executed.

Comment: any particular reason trying to use double slashes in a url?

Comment: @Konerak Ah yes, you are right.  @yoda I was simply trying to get the second rule to apply

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Strangely enough,

```
RewriteRule   ^/help    help.php?q=2              [L]
```

The above rule fails and never matches.

This rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^help      help.php?q=1             [L]
```

Matches http://localhost/help, http://localhost//help and http://localhost///help

It appears RewriteRule *never* sees leading slashes of the path, and as TheCoolah said [they are collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514627/apache-rewrite-rule-leading-slash/4514696#4514696) (to 0.. when using a .htaccess file anyway) no matter how many there are.

For the second part of the question,

```
RewriteRule   ^help    /help.php
```

I'm getting the answer from [Definitive Guide to Apache Mod_rewrite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595610)

> ... a rewrite target that does not begin with http:// or another protocol
> designator is assumed to be a file system path.  File paths that do not begin with a slash are interpreted as being relative to the directory in which the rewriting is taking place.

So /help.php looks in the root of the system for a file called help.php, which on my system it cannot find.

To make /help.php appear as a relative URL (relative to the root of the site) you can use the [PT] directive:

```
RewriteRule   ^/help    /help.php    [PT]
```

That directs http://localhost/help  to http://localhost/help.php.

Comment: It looks like the leading slash does indeed match if you put the rule in the vhost config, but not in a directory context.

Comment: Interestingly, `RedirectMatch` needs the leading slash in the pattern

Answer (score 4):

Regarding double slashes: Most Web servers silently collapse multiple slashes into a single slash early in the request processing pipeline. This is true for at least Apache, Tomcat and Jetty. Most Unix-based file systems work the same way. If you really want to check for this, you need to do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
```

Answer (score 3):

`help` matches "help" anywhere in the path.

`/help` matches nothing since the `rewriterule` directive omits the leading slash for matching purposes (i.e., you must use `^`, not `/` or `^/`, to reference the current directory).

(This can be very confusing if you've used `%{REQUEST_URI}` in `rewritecond` because `%{REQUEST_URI}` *does* begin with a trailing slash. When matching against `%{REQUEST_URI}`, `^` and `^/` are equivalent and a directory name will always be preceded by a slash character regardless of whether or not it is in the top-level directory.)

The server error is caused by an infinite loop. "help" becomes "/help.php" which is then matched by the same directive that did the rewriting. So, after the first match, "/help.php" becomes "/help.php" infinitely resulting in a URL that can't be resolved.

I believe such loops can be fixed with the `end` flag (i.e., `[end]`), but that flag requires Apache 2.3.9+ whereas Apache 2.2 seems to be more common in deployment. It'd probably be better to just fix the regular expression anyway; `^help$` would seem to be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

The way RewriteRule works is that if the given regular expression matches any part of the path part of the URL (the part after the host and port but before the query string), then the entire path part is completely replaced with the given substitution.  This explains the behaviour you're seeing in the first part of your question.

I'm not sure what could be causing the 500 errors on the second part; maybe the collapsing of doubled slashes doesn't happen after the rewrite engine has run and then generates a server error.

Comment: Note also that, unless you specify a special continue flag (which I can't remember), further rewrite rules are not applied after it finds a match; and the matching happens from first to last among those specified.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the 500 Error is an infinitive Loop:

- help gets rewritten to /help
- /help gets stripped to help
- help gets rewritten to /help
  etc. until the MaxRewrites limit is hit -> 500

Whereas if the rule rewrites help to help, Apache is smart enough to abort rewriting at that point.

Comment: No, its due to the leading slash in the destination of the re-write makes the dest interpretted as an absolute path to a file on the hdd, see my answer