# 301 Redirect - htaccess redirecting a .asp file

Tags: asp.net, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Question:

How do i 301 redirect in .htaccess the following line:

```
Redirect 301   /reizen.asp?type=ind     http://domain.com/individuele-reizen
Redirect 301   /reis.asp?reisID=169     http://domain.com/individuele-reizen/oostenrijk/tirol-karinthie
```

I keep getting: error:

```
The requested URL /reis.asp was not found on this server.
```

A search on stack overflow did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match QUERY_STRING using `Rediect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=ind$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?reizen\.asp$ /individuele-reizen? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^reisID=169$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?reis\.asp$ /individuele-reizen/oostenrijk/tirol-karinthie? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the leading slash: `^/?` is necessary? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514627/apache-rewrite-rule-leading-slash

Comment: I have leading slash optional if you notice. It is used when used in Apache config but not used when used in .htaccess. Making it optional makes rule work in both places.

Comment: Thank you anubhava, at the end of my URL the ?type=ind is added. how to fix that?

Comment: @anubhava I see. I thought, that this rule will be used only in .htaccess the PO said: "How do i 301 redirect in .htaccess"

Comment: @DaanVerberne: Check edited answer. This will strip any query string in resulting URI.