# Clarifications on this RewriteRule Apache HTTP mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to ask some basic clarifications on this mod_rewrite RewriteRule of Apache, cause I have found different explanations and maybe I am missing something:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

This rule is supposed to rewrite every request to the index.php (in the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory) when the requested resource extension is NOT one of those hardcoded in the sub-pattern of the regexp at the condition that the resource is NOT a local file, but what differs this rule from this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

? They're exactly the same if not that the substitution string in the second rule (*index.php*) is **without the leading slash**.

Now, a user here -> [Apache rewrite rule leading slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514627/apache-rewrite-rule-leading-slash/4514696#4514836) says that:

```
So /help.php looks in the root of the system for a file called help.php, which on my system it cannot find.
```

Shouldn't it be so even for the */index.php* (the substitution string in the first rule I have posted)?

Then I would like to ask:
if the request is for example to `http://localhost/a_file_that_don't_exist.php` Apache is going to match against *a_file_that_don't_exist.php* or against */a_file_that_don't_exist.php*?

In the wiki -> https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule they say that Apache will:

> match against the URI-path

That is:

> everything after `http://hostname`, and not including any query string arguments

But in some tutorials about RewriteRule people say that URI-path is everything after `http://hostname/`, thus NOT including the leading slash (REQUEST_URI without the leading slash).

Could someone elucidate this misunderstandings, please?

Cause if pattern matches without the leading slash, the first RewriteRule should replace the URI-path to -> `http://localhost//index.php` which is not a valid URL, but instead it works beautifully both ways...

EDIT: in the Apache docs they say:

> Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a
>   file-system path or a URL-path by checking to see if the first segment
>   of the path exists at the root of the file-system. For example, if you
>   specify a Substitution string of /www/file.html, then this will be
>   treated as a URL-path unless a directory named www exists at the root
>   or your file-system (or, in the case of using rewrites in a .htaccess
>   file, relative to your document root), in which case it will be
>   treated as a file-system path.

So is it correctly to say that in .htaccess RewriteRules are always relative to the DOCUMENT_ROOT if they start with a leading slash and relative to the .htaccess directory if without the leading slash?

Comment: no, read up on [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html).  In the second case you are moving the document root to `/` -- no change in other words.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand, could you please show an example?

Comment: Look for `^localpath(.*) /otherpath$1` in [mod_rewrite](http://apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation.

Comment: Sorry but why there's a ^? The localpath is not at the start of the URL-part, cause the request is made to /somepath/localpath/pathinfo... I am sorry but I'm getting more confused, why '^localpath(.*)' should match */somepath/localpath/pathinfo* ?

Comment: I am getting more frustrated.  Please read what I wrote.  You asked what is the difference between `index.php` and `/index.php`.  I was just giving you a search key to find the right section in the Apache documentation.  Please read the bit of f***ing documentation that I pointed you to which explains how mod_rewrite interprets the leading / in the replacement string!!

Comment: Yes I read it, please check my EDIT. I do not want to make you angry, I just didn't completely understand that cause I am new to mod_rewrite, so I think there's no need to respond in such a way, cause we are all here to learn and improve our knowledge, anyway I am sorry if my doubts touched you.

Comment: You need to differentiate between the subjects of the pattern match which work as you say: in the case of directory relative (as in `.htaccess` rules) then the leading `/` should be omitted in the pattern.  The section that I asked you to read explains how the substitution string is interpreted.  `/index.php` means `index.php` in the path `/` -- that is DOCROOT, which if you are already in DOCROOT is effectively the same as `index.php` as you have found.  If I ask you to read a particular section then it would really help if you bothered to _read_ it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, anyway, I'll keep reading!