# Rewrite rule is not working in apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to url rewriting, and saw many tutorials for url rewriting like,

[url-rewriting-for-beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

I have used the following code in .htaccess,

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule    ^/raipur/([0-9])$ /viewRestaurant.php?id=$1   [NC,L]
```

and testing on this page [urlRewritetest.php](http://foodinger.in/urlRewritetest.php).

code of urlRewritetest.php

```
<a href="/raipur/2">click</a>
```

but its not working, I am using ipage's server, and also when i try to see the log using RewriteLog, the page through Internal Server Error,

Can anyone please suggest my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you remove the first slash in your RewriteRule? You may also want to add "+" after the digits to match more than one digit.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^raipur/([0-9]+)$ /viewRestaurant.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me, but can you please tell me why does / causing the problem

Comment: Have a look at accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514627/apache-rewrite-rule-leading-slash