# Set URL subdirectory in a GET element

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following directory on my Server:

```
Document Root
|
|- index.php 
|
|- /wiki
|    |
|    |-index.php
|    |
|    |-home.md
|    | 
|    |-foo.md
|    |
|    |-folder
|    |   |
|    |   |- foo.md

... and so on
```

I would like rewrite the ULR for the Wiki path. For example:

> http://DOMAIN.tld/wiki/foo

Should be server side

> http://DOMAIN.tld/wiki/?page=foo

and

> http://DOMAIN.tld/wiki/folder/foo

Should be server side

> http://DOMAIN.tld/wiki/?page=folder/foo

My idea is, transform the subdirectories to a GET element. In PHP, I can split the directory by `/` and perform my evaluation (PHP). After the `wiki`folder could be endless subfolder.

I use Apache (Plesk as Webserver) and PHP 7.

I tried following code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/wiki/(.*) /wiki/?page=$1
```

and my PHP code for testing (/wiki/index.php)

```
echo 'Hello Wiki';    
echo $_GET['page'];
```

If I call `http://DOMAIN.dtl/wiki`i got the wiki page.
If I call `http://DOMAIN.dtl/wiki/test`I got the 404 ERROR.

My question is: where is my mistake. I'm very grateful for every hint.

## Edit:

change my `htaccess` file to :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*) wiki?page=$1
```

Now I got following error message (Browser Safari): `ERROR: Too many redirections`

Comment: Remove leading slash. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514836/1219741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting rewrite loop error due to the identical url pattern and destination path sincr **wiki/index.php?page=** also matches the pattern 
**^wiki/(.*)** . To fix this, you need  to exclude the destination path :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/wiki/index.php$ 
 RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*) wiki?page=$1
```