# Why is my code in the htaccess file not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the htacces file to modify the urls of my site and I have a problem, I want to convert this url http://localhost/ejemplo/edicionpelicula.php?id=7 in this http://localhost/ejemplo/edicionpelicula=7.I mean that if I use this url it will send me to where the other one does. I have written this code but it doesn't work correctly.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^edicionpelicula=([0-9]+)$ edicionpelicula.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This code "RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]" I use it to remove php extensions.

This is the wrong code,i think:

```
   RewriteRule ^edicionpelicula=([0-9]+)$ edicionpelicula.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Do you know how to fix it, thank you.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What is not working? If you access your page through such a short URL, does it work properly?

Comment: I want to convert this url http://localhost/ejemplo/edicionpelicula.php?id=7 in this http://localhost/ejemplo/edicionpelicula=7 and the code that does not work is this RewriteRule ^edicionpelicula=([0-9]+)$ edicionpelicula.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Oh,maybe I expressed myself wrong,I want to make the url more friendly and for that if I use the second url it will send me where the first one sends me,that's what the htacces file is for I think.

Comment: Also if using [L] rules after the first match are not considered, and your `^([^\.]+)$` will match many paths.

Comment: i made the cagens but it still does not work,this is the new code: RewriteRule ^/edicionpelicula=([0-9]+)$ /edicionpelicula.php?id=$1

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: "Paths always start with a `/`, so `^edic..` can never match" - When used in `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ never starts with a slash. @TobiasK.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite, I didn't verify it actually, so sorry for the misinformation. In nginx and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514627/apache-rewrite-rule-leading-slash/4514696#comment15060960_4514836 +my exp even Apache vhost context it includes the slash, so this was a naive assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` matches and causes a rewrite (tested with `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`):

```
[perdir /var/www/html/ejemplo/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/ejemplo/edicionpelicula=7 -> edicionpelicula=7
[perdir /var/www/html/ejemplo/] rewrite 'edicionpelicula=7' -> 'edicionpelicula=7.php'
```

to a PHP file that does not exist (`edicionpelicula=7.php`), so you get a 404. Because of `[L]` no further rules are processed (would match on the rewritten URL anyways).

You can either just remove that rule, following works in my testsetup:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^edicionpelicula=([0-9]+)$ edicionpelicula.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Or adjust the generic rule to include your `=` pattern/logic:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)=(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```